# utf-8 in JSON And Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

im using json and volley in my project to feed database rows in my mainactivity as rows with cardview and recyclerview , but i want to make my json to the utf-8 to show some arabic words
how should i exactly do??

this is the part of my JsonArrayRequest code
thank you

```
    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
    //Initializing ProgressBar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //Displaying Progressbar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                    parseData(response);
                    //Hiding the progressbar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "تمامی آگهی ها بارگذاری شدند", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should to convert your strings response in `parseNetworkResponse`  before volley calls `onResponse`

```
@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse (NetworkResonse response) {
    try {
        String utf8_response = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(utf8_response ), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        //do something
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a great solution but I already tried it from another answer and the result is still "??????". The service returns proper text but Volley downloads gibberish. I will have to try the other one now.

Comment: This worked. My django console was showing correct emojis and database was also correct. Bad things happened when my custom VolleyJsonArrayRequest class received the string from the server (using the wrong encoding) this made the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Extract your JSON Object then :

```
byte ptext[] = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Sorry , im beginner in json and volley, can you explain that anymore?? Thank you so much

Comment: @K1-Aria ok, you retrieve your data in JSON format, JSON array is a ordered collection of values, which are enclosed within brackets e.g. [] and separated by comma. when u get your jsonArray you need to convert it to String array, as far as i understand ur json only contains strings in Farsi language. when u convert ur josn object to java object then u can encode it to UTF-8 accordingly.
http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2013/04/convert-json-array-to-string-array-list-java-from.html this link teaches u how to convert json to java object. moafagh bashi :)